# assign cuda to a specific gpu

Tags: nvidia, environment-variables, cuda

Two NVIDIA 780Ti cards installed. Using cuda 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. Postinstallation checklist shows cuda installed properly and functions properly. My monitors are attached to device 0. I compiled the cuda samples and ran nvidia-smi. ITs output shows two NVIDIA cards as expected:

```
Fri Apr  1 01:04:31 2016       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.79     Driver Version: 352.79         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 38%   50C    P2    N/A /  N/A |   1084MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 780 Ti  Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 29%   34C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     11MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However deviceQuery only shows 1 card:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 780 Ti"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5
  Total amount of global memory:                 3072 MBytes (3221028864 bytes)
  (15) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     2880 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1084 MHz (1.08 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             3500 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1572864 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 3 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 780 Ti
Result = PASS
```

I tried to direct cuda to the other video card using the environment variable

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1

I added the line

```
 export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
```

to .bashrc and opened a new terminal window. Printenv showed me 
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 among others.

I ran bandwidthTest. Its output is:

```
[CUDA Bandwidth Test] - Starting...
Running on...

 Device 0: GeForce GTX 780 Ti
 Quick Mode

 Host to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)    Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432         11618.3

 Device to Host Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)    Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432         12909.9

 Device to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)    Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432         265048.1

Result = PASS
```

I rebooted and reran bandwidthTest but it still starts its output with:

```
[CUDA Bandwidth Test] - Starting...
    Running on...

     Device 0: GeForce GTX 780 Ti
     Quick Mode
```

bandwidthTest is STILL using Device 0. I want it to use device 1. Why did deviceQuery only see one card? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

it seems this is a problem with deviceQuery.

When I start

```
nvidia-smi -l 1 --query --display=PERFORMANCE >> gpu_utillization.log
```

and then start a cuda compiled sample app, particles

The log shows something interesting. 
At 'rest', before particles is started, GPU0 is in performance state 2 and GPU1 is in performance state 8.
After particles is started, both performance states are 0.

After quitting particles the performance states return to baseline. GPU0 is tunning my displays so I imagine that is why it never goes to state 8.

[This](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__gpupstate.html) explains performance states.

```
P0/P1 - Maximum 3D performance
P2/P3 - Balanced 3D performance-power
P8 - Basic HD video playback
P10 - DVD playback
P12 - Minimum idle power consumption
```